# MVC4 - EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning code first approach.

I created a EbuyDataContext4.cs file with:

```
namespace Ebuy.Website.Models
{
    public class EbuyDataContext4 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and i use it in creating and saving one form based on a model.

I have 2 questions:

1. Where the data is being saved?
2. If i change something in the model, i receive an error that my dbContext have a problem because of those changes. I solve it by deleting it and creating another dbContext (for now i have dbContext3) but i guess there is a smarter way to solve this error...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the MSDN documentation explains all of this quite nicely; a quick Google would have solved this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of using code first is very usefull when you are starting a new project from the Scratch.

First of all, the data will be saved in a database with the same name as the DataContext, in your case is EbuyDataContext4. The EF will create the entire database from the specified model.

Second, as you are taking the way of Code-First, every time you update any class model you must update it in the database, so put this code below at the App_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EbuyDataContext>());
}
```

Hopes its help you! And take a look here [Entity Framework Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh972463.aspx) for more info!

Comment: thanks! Although i really prefer the DB-first approach since i like to design tables before i start programming. But i guess its good to know all kind of approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1-By default, Entity Framework creates a database on the local SQL Express instance with the same name/namespace as your dbcontext.

2-You should look into Code First Migrations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) This allows you to change your model without the recreating that you're doing.

Comment: 1. And where i can see it? :) (the app_data folder is empty)\

Comment: The database created is not included in the solution by the EF, click to see all hidden files. If is not present, the EF creates it in the default database configured in Asp.net default sql instace. Probably the Express instalation if you have it!

Answer (score 0):

To know where your data is saved take a look into your web.config.
First look what context you are using if you did not specify that further you probably will use the DefaultConnection (search for this string in web.config).

Indeed if you change your model, that will get your application to crash since it still runs against an unupdated database (that does not reflect your changes).

For testing and development (not production though ;))

I'd advise you to use an initializer that will ensure initial data and the structure while you are still fiddling with it.

create a file containing the initializer code somewhere in your project (just sample identifiers):

```
namespace DataAccess.DAL
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    /// <summary>
    /// This class initializes the ArticleContext's data every time something in the model (POCOs) changed
    /// </summary>
    public class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbContext>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Seeds the specified context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
        {
//place initializer code here
            //var items = new List<Item);
            //items .ForEach(a => context.Items.Add(a));
            //context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

you may have to add some references to your project...
Then in global.asax wire up your initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new Initializer());
```